# How does #define carries the function name in c?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

After working for more than 10 years, today a code caught my eye, I am unable to understand the function name defined inside a function gets printed in the output/log without being passed as an argument in macro or being defined as a global variable. Please help me understanding the internal. Please see the screenshot for the reference.

```
/*...*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define x printf("%s", f);
int main() {
    char *f = "MAIN";
    printf("Hello World");
    x;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello WorldMAIN
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please post code as text.

Comment: 1) Please do NOT post images; copy/paste your code as TEXT. 2) read up on C macros: [#define](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php).  All it does is "substitute text".  3) Specifically, wherever the C preprocessor sees "x", it will substitute the text `printf("%s", f);` before passing it on to the compiler.  4) This particular macro is BAD ... for many, many different reasons.  Please consider getting rid of it!

Comment: [C Preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor), see the section on [Replacing text macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace).

Comment: large or small, it's irrelevant. You have more than 11k reputation and still do that silly thing? [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C preprocessor macros simply do text replacement. They have no semantic awareness of your program.

This:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define x printf("%s", f);

int main()
{ 
    char* f = "MAIN";  
    printf ("Hello World");
    x;
    return 0;
}
```

Becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    char* f = "MAIN";  
    printf ("Hello World");
    printf("%s", f);;
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that if there is no `f` declared when this macro is used, you will see a compiler error. If `f` is declared, but is not a `char *`, you should see compiler *warnings*.

Some preprocessor macro best practices include (but are not limited to) using capitalized names, as `x` by convention looks like a variable or function name; and being careful about what syntactically significant symbols (in this case `;`) you include in your macro text.

Hopefully this example was done for the sake of learning, because it is wholly unnecessary. Preprocessor macros wouldn't exist if they didn't serve a purpose, but beware they can easily obfuscate code.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation, and for pointing out some of the issues in the OP's example macro.  Macros can be extremely useful.  But the OP's macro is an excellent example of how NOT to use macros.  It's a [coding horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor macros are just text replacements. All `#include` statements are replaced with the content of the specified files.  All occurrences of `#define`'d symbols are replaced with their specified text. All comments are omitted. Etc...

So, in your example:

```
/*...*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define x printf("%s", f);
int main() {
    char *f = "MAIN";
    printf("Hello World");
    x;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The preprocessor replaces all instances of `x` with the text `printf("%s", f);` before the processed code is then sent to the compiler.  So, this is the code that the compiler actually sees:

```
// contents of <stdio.h> here...

int main() {
    char *f = "MAIN";
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("%s", f);;
    
    return 0;
}
```